# how to search in the database when the user completes entering the input tag

Tags: ajax

i want to search the related information in the database when the user enters his mobile number. I want to start the search as soon as the user enters the last digit of his cell number

I just want to know how to trigger the AJAX.

Comment: How would you know which digit is the last one?

Comment: @ Jukka K. Korpela hii....the user will enter his cell number so, 10th digit will be the last digit.....i want to autofill his address if the database already has the number registered.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to know is described in the [jQuery ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)